# Camel routing between EJBs

Tags: java, ejb, messaging, apache-camel

I just need confirmation/clarification on my understanding of some Apache Camel basics. If I have a backend that consists of many EJBs, and I want to use a service bus like Camel to wire them together in various ways, then I imagine there must be someway of defining each EJB as an "endpoint" (my ESB terminology is still *in development*) and then to send messages to those endpoints? If so, can someone provide or point me to a working code example that demonstrates this, and if not, can someone explain to me how EJBs can communicate over Camel?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see [camel-ejb](http://camel.apache.org/ejb.html) for an overview and take a look at this unit test for a working example...

https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/camel/trunk/components/camel-ejb/src/test/java/org/apache/camel/component/ejb/GreaterCamelEjbTest.java